# Impossible to boot Ubuntu after shut-down during system upgrade

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, xubuntu

My computer has Xubuntu and Windows 10 installed in dual boot.

Unfortunately, during the system upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04, my computer shut down. 
Now, it is impossible to boot Xubuntu, I can only obtain a black screen with the following message:

```
Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init.
/bin/sh: 0: Can't open splash
[    3.280588] Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00007f00
[    3.280588]
[    3.280625] CPU: 3 PID: 1 Comm: sh Not tainted 3.13.0-92-generic #139-Ubuntu
[    3.280653] Hardware name: ASUSTeK Cumputer Inc. K53SD/K53SD, BIOS K53SD.204 01/17/2012
[    3.280683]  0000000000000000 ffff8801c6539e48 ffffffff81729e66 ffffffff81a50e68
[    3.280778]  ffff8801c26c2a00 ffff8801c6539ec0 ffffffff81722ca8 ffffffff00000010
[    3.280870]  ffff8801c6539ed0 ffff8801c6539e70 ffffffff81f25aa0 0000000000007f00
[    3.280964] Call Trace:
[    3.280991]  [<ffffffff81729e66>] dump_stack+0x64/0x82
[    3.281015]  [<ffffffff81722ca8>] panic+0xc8/0c1e1
[    3.281046]  [<ffffffff8106c5b1>] do_exit+0xa51/0xa60
[    3.281072]  [<ffffffff8106c63f>] do_group_exit+0x3f/0xa0
[    3.281099]  [<ffffffff8106c6b4>] SyS_exit_group+0x14/0x20
[    3.281127]  [<ffffffff8173a9dd>] system_call_fastpath+0x1a/0x1f
```

The content of this message is the same for any recovery booting option I can choose.

From Windows, I am able to access the files from my Linux partition using Ext2Fsd. So, I wanted to know if that could be a way to repair my Xubuntu install, or if there is any other way to repair/restore it.

Comment: Can you still boot to a prior kernel from GRUB? Can you get to recovery mode from GRUB?

Comment: Yes I can, but as I wrote, I get the same error message using any version of recovery mode from GRUB

Comment: Can you boot to a Xubuntu LiveCD? If so, open FILES from the launcher, and click on the name of the Ubuntu partition on the hard disk, so it can mount it for you. Then open TERMINAL from the dash, and type df, and look for something like /dev/sdan (where n is a number 0-8) in the left column. Using that /dev/sdan, type: fsck -f /dev/sdan, and lets see if it can find any file/directory corruption. If this doesn't work, then I'd recommend reinstalling Xubuntu.

Comment: ps: I'd recommend not using any software under Windows that allows you access to the Linux file system. My experience is that they corrupt the Linux file system.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to recover Xubuntu, but I really don't recommend you to even try. Shutting down a system during a full upgrade can do nothing as well as it can break your system apart (which probably happened to you).

Backup everything you need from Xubuntu and install it again (preferably from a fresh 16.04 ISO).

It's always good to download a fresh copy every time you upgrade, since things like this can happen.